# Mapping DH / DHE p & g params to a group

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, tls

I'm doing a small code that performs a simple SSL/TLS analysis and I'm stuck on determining the size of the key exchange in the case of DH / DHE.

If I take the following example (wireshark capture) :

```
p Length: 128
p: acb31[...]
g Length: 1
g: 02
Pubkey Length: 128
Pubkey: 1935[...]
```

I just thought I could get the necessary information from G [regarding this article](https://infosecmonkey.com/what-diffie-hellman-dh-group-should-i-use/)

But it doesn't seem to be the case, because for another configuration I get

```
p Length: 256
p: a4d37[...]
g Length: 1
g: 02
Pubkey Length: 256
Pubkey: 4671[...]
```

The value of G is always 2, so the exchange key should be 1024, except that my exchange key is 2048 for this case.

How can I determine the size of my exchange key via theses settings? Can I just do p*8 ?
Thanks for the help

Comment: The article you link is about DH in IPsec/IKE which uses standardized groups. TLS 1.2 and below (which you obviously have) can use any server-defined group, and many servers have created their own group (because lots of uninformed websites have recommended that, voodoo-like). For what is now retronymed FFDH (aka classic, integer, modp) TLS1.2 can use, and TLS1.3 always uses, standardized groups in a way similar to IKE but not exactly the same; see rfc7919.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases the system is determined by the prime $p$ (you can check that the values `0xabc31...` and `0x a4d37...` are prime if you wish). The size of the prime in bytes can be read from the `p Length` so that in bits it is 8 times this value (assuming that the most significant bit is set).

The public key is then $2^r\mod p$ for some secret random number $r$ when $g=2$ as is the case. This public key can be anywhere in the range $[1,p-1]$, but is very likely to be the same length in bytes as $p$. It is possible that smaller public keys will be produced, and the packet formatting may or may not pad this out to the same length as $p$.